# Parts of speech tags in a list?

Tags: nlp

Given the sentence `"The cat sat on the mat."`, I want the list of tuples: `{{"The", "Determiner"}, {"cat", "Noun"}, {"sat", "Verb"}, ...}`, these are the part-of-speech tags.

`TextStructure` should be able to do this, but it really can't:

```
TextStructure["The cat sat on the mat.", #] & /@ {"ConstituentTree", 
  "ConstituentGraphs", "ConstituentStrings", "PartsOfSpeech", 
  "DependencyGraphs", "DependencyStrings"}
```

It gives a lot of fancy plots and things, but not the most basic and useful thing - the list of {word, postag} tuples.

Extracting the second row from the plot would be a sufficient answer.

**Related:**

- [Can Mathematica determine part-of-speech for each word in a text?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38053/can-mathematica-determine-part-of-speech-for-each-word-in-a-text)
- [Extracting Parts of Speech](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185039/extracting-parts-of-speech)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many structures in Mathematica have a special display form, but there is always the standard expression "behind the scenes".

```
TextStructure["The cat sat on the mat.", "PartsOfSpeech"]//FullForm
```

You'll see that the underlying expression has a head of TextElement. It turns out that the bits you want are at level 4.

```
Cases[TextStructure["The cat sat on the mat.", "PartsOfSpeech"], _TextElement, {4}]
```

These are also TextElements (and so will have that special display form). You can unwrap these to get what you want. Putting it all together:

```
{#[[1]], CommonName[#[[2]]["GrammaticalUnit"]]} & /@
  Cases[TextStructure["The cat sat on the mat.", "PartsOfSpeech"], _TextElement, {4}]
```

`{{The,determiner},{cat,noun},{sat,verb},{on,preposition},{the,determiner},{mat,noun},{.,punctuation}}`

(Or maybe you want CanonicalName instead of CommonName.)

Comment: TextStructure should support this directly

Answer (score 1):

A list can be obtained using `Normal` and processed further.

```
str = "The cat sat on the mat."
(TextStructure[str, "PartsOfSpeech"] // Normal // Level[#, {-1}] &) /.
    "GrammaticalUnit" -> Nothing // Partition[#, 2] & // TableForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{The} & \text{Determiner} \\
 \text{cat} & \text{Noun} \\
 \text{sat} & \text{Verb} \\
 \text{on} & \text{Preposition} \\
 \text{the} & \text{Determiner} \\
 \text{mat} & \text{Noun} \\
 . & \text{Punctuation} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, but this is overly complicated step shouldn't be necessary to extract such straightforward and important info, bad design on the part of TextStructure

Comment: It is perhaps useful as an input to some other framework or grammar processing tool; but I am not aware of it currently. Such design decisions are never random.